# xlsm files merging error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid row number (-1) outside allowable range (0..1048575)

Tags: java, apache-poi

I tried to merge 2 xlsx files and code executed fine and merging happened. With same code, I tried to merge 2 xlsm files. Those are files with macro codes.

> DataWillBeMerged2.xlsm Copying.. Copying.. Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid row number (-1) outside
> allowable range (0..1048575)  at
> org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.setRowNum(XSSFRow.java:423)     at
> org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.createRow(XSSFSheet.java:788)
> at
> MergeMultipleXlsFilesInDifferentSheet.copySheets(MergeMultipleXlsFilesInDifferentSheet.java:58)
> at
> MergeMultipleXlsFilesInDifferentSheet.copySheets(MergeMultipleXlsFilesInDifferentSheet.java:48)
> at
> MergeMultipleXlsFilesInDifferentSheet.mergeExcelFiles(MergeMultipleXlsFilesInDifferentSheet.java:31)
> at
> MergeMultipleXlsFilesInDifferentSheet.main(MergeMultipleXlsFilesInDifferentSheet.java:122)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class MergeMultipleXlsFilesInDifferentSheet{
 public static void mergeExcelFiles(File file) throws IOException {
    XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook();
    System.out.println(file.getName());
    String directoryName = "C:\\input";
    File directory = new File(directoryName);
    //get all the files from a directory
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file1 : fList){
        if (file1.isFile()){
            String ParticularFile = file1.getName();
       FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File(directoryName+"\\"+ParticularFile));
      XSSFWorkbook b = new XSSFWorkbook(fin);
      for (int i = 0; i < b.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
          XSSFSheet sheet = book.createSheet(b.getSheetName(i));
        copySheets(book, sheet, b.getSheetAt(i));
        System.out.println("Copying..");
      }
    }
    try {
      writeFile(book, file);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  }
  protected static void writeFile(XSSFWorkbook book, File file) throws Exception {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    book.write(out);
    out.close();
  }
  private static void copySheets(XSSFWorkbook newWorkbook, XSSFSheet newSheet, XSSFSheet sheet){     
    copySheets(newWorkbook, newSheet, sheet, true);
  }     

  private static void copySheets(XSSFWorkbook newWorkbook, XSSFSheet newSheet, XSSFSheet sheet, boolean copyStyle){     
    int newRownumber = 0;
    int maxColumnNum = 0;     
    Map<Integer, XSSFCellStyle> styleMap = (copyStyle) ? new HashMap<Integer, XSSFCellStyle>() : null;    

    for (int i = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {     
      XSSFRow srcRow = sheet.getRow(i);     
      XSSFRow destRow = newSheet.createRow(i + newRownumber);     
      if (srcRow != null) {     
        copyRow(newWorkbook, sheet, newSheet, srcRow, destRow, styleMap);     
        if (srcRow.getLastCellNum() > maxColumnNum) {     
            maxColumnNum = srcRow.getLastCellNum();     
        }     
      }     
    }     
    for (int i = 0; i <= maxColumnNum; i++) {     
      newSheet.setColumnWidth(i, sheet.getColumnWidth(i));     
    }     
  }     

  public static void copyRow(XSSFWorkbook newWorkbook, XSSFSheet srcSheet, XSSFSheet destSheet, XSSFRow srcRow, XSSFRow destRow, Map<Integer, XSSFCellStyle> styleMap) {     
    destRow.setHeight(srcRow.getHeight());
    for (int j = srcRow.getFirstCellNum(); j <= srcRow.getLastCellNum(); j++) {     
      XSSFCell oldCell = srcRow.getCell(j);
      XSSFCell newCell = destRow.getCell(j);
      if (oldCell != null) {     
        if (newCell == null) {     
          newCell = destRow.createCell(j);     
        }     
        copyCell(newWorkbook, oldCell, newCell, styleMap);
      }     
    }                
  }

  public static void copyCell(XSSFWorkbook newWorkbook, XSSFCell oldCell, XSSFCell newCell, Map<Integer, XSSFCellStyle> styleMap) {      
    if(styleMap != null) {     
      int stHashCode = oldCell.getCellStyle().hashCode();     
      XSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = styleMap.get(stHashCode);     
      if(newCellStyle == null){     
        newCellStyle = newWorkbook.createCellStyle();     
        newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());     
        styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);     
      }     
      newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);   
    }     
    switch(oldCell.getCellType()) {     
      case STRING:     
        newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getRichStringCellValue());     
        break;     
      case NUMERIC:     
        newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getNumericCellValue());     
        break;     
    //  case BLANK: 
          //return null;
       // newCell.setCellType(null);     
       // break;     
      case BOOLEAN:     
        newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getBooleanCellValue());     
        break;     
      case ERROR:     
        newCell.setCellErrorValue(oldCell.getErrorCellValue());     
        break;     
      case FORMULA:     
        newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());     
        break;     
      default:     
        break;     
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
        mergeExcelFiles(new File("C:\\DataWillBeMerged2.xlsm"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How many rows do the two files have been them?

Comment: What is `i` when the error occurs? It will be `-1` if `sheet` is an empty sheet having no rows.

Comment: In 1st workbook, 4 sheets are available in which 1 is empty. Any suggestion to fix this error?

Comment: my requirement is even if book1 have empty sheet, book1 and book2 should merge